# Cant link CSS stylesheet to Index.html?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying every conceivable combination of the link in the style tag to link my CSS content with my html template. PLEASE HELP!

And before anyone asks if my style sheet and index.html files are in the same file location, they are.

THANKS IN ADVANCE for any help offered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.  You're missing a `"`.

Comment: Please be so polite to read the [tour]. There is no need TO SHOUT, or beg or thank in advance. A little more care about spelling is appreciated ("Cant", a question about singing on SO?)

Comment: `href="style.css"`

Comment: Correct spelling is "musician".

Answer (score -1):

Do this simple correction:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "mainstyle.css">
```